# Choosing databasetype for a decentralized calendar project

Tags: java, database, calendar, distributed, cap-theorem

I am developing a calendar system which is decentralised. It should save the data on each device and synchronise if they have both internet connection. My first idea was, just using a relational database and try to synchronise data after connection. But the theory says something else. [The Brewers CAP-Theorem](https://howtodoinjava.com/hadoop/brewers-cap-theorem-in-simple-words/) describes the theory behind it, but i am not sure if this theorem maybe is outdated. If i use this theorem i have "AP [Availability/Partition Tolerance] Systems". "A" because i need at any given time the data for my calendar and "P" because it can happen, that there is no connection between the devices and the data can't be synchronised.  The example databases are CouchDB, RIAK or Cassandra. I have worked only with relational databases and doesn't know how to go on now. Is it that bad to use a relational Database for my project?

This is for my bachelor thesis. I just wanted to start using Postgres but then i found this theorem...
The whole project is based on Java.

Comment: if you plan use database, not matter relational one or NOSQL one. You are centralizing, right? Why not use REAL p2p way?

Comment: @yuanqingfei can you please be more specific about the real p2p way? Do you mean distributed database?

Comment: Behzad, the "p2p" (if you want to call it that...) way is to hold the data separately on each device. On a smartphone it might be some sort of simple local database implementation, and on a server it might be some big-name DB implementation, but these two are separate. The question then becomes how to reconcile the difference that happen between these two systems. I gave some ideas in my long answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the CAP theorem isn't really helpful to your scenario. Distributed systems that deal with partitions need to decide what to when one part wants to make a modification to the data, but can't reach the other part. One solution is to make the write wait - and this is giving up the "availability" because of the "partition", one of the options presented by the CAP theorem. But there are more useful options. The most useful (highly-available) option is to allow both parts to be written independently, and **reconcile** the conflicts when they can connect again. The question is how to do that, and different distributed systems choose different approaches.

Some systems, like Cassandra or Amazon's DynamoDB, use "last writer wins" - when we see a conflict between two conflicting writes, the last one (according some synchronized clock) wins. For this approach to make sense you need to be very careful about how you model your data (e.g., watch out for cases where the conflict resolution results in an invalid mixture of two states).

In other systems (and also in Cassandra and DynamoDB - in their "collection" types) writes can still happen independently on different nodes, but there is more sophisticat conflict resolution. A good example is Cassandra's "list": One can send an update saying "add item X to the list", and another update saying "add item Y to the list". If these updates happen on different partitions, the conflict is later resolved by adding *both* X and Y to the list. The data structures such as this list - which allows the content to be modified independently in certain ways on two nodes and then automatically reconciled in a sensible way, is known as a [Conflict-free Replicated Data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type) (CRDT).

Finally, another approach was used in Amazon's Dynamo paper (not to be confused by their current DynamoDB service!), known as "vector clocks": When you want to write to an object - e.g., a shopping cart - you first read the current state of the object and get with it a "vector clock", which you can think of as the "version" of the data you got. You then make the modification (e.g., add an item to the shopping cart), and write back the new version while saying what was the old version you started with. If two of these modifications happen on parallel on different partitions, we later need to reconcile the two updates. The vector clocks allow the system to determine if one modification is "newer" than the other (in which case there is no conflict), or they really do conflict. And when they do, application-specific logic is used to reconcile the conflict. In the shopping cart example, if we see the conflict is that in one partition item A was added to the shopping cart and in the other partition, item B was added to the shopping cart, the straightforward resolution is to just add both times A and B to the shopping cart.

You should probably pick one of these approaches. Just saying "the CAP theorem doesn't let me do this" is usually not an option ;-) In fact, in some ways, the problem you're facing is **different** than some of the systems I mentioned. In those systems, the common case is every node is always connected (no partition), with very low latency, and they want this common case to be fast. In your case, you can probably assume the opposite: the two parts are usually not connected, or if they are connected there is high latency, so conflict resolution because the norm, rather than the exception. So you need to decide how to do this conflict resolution - what happens if one adds a meeting on one device and a different meeting on the other device (most likely, just keep both as two meetings...), how do you know that one device modified a pre-existing meeting and didn't add a second meeting (vector clocks? unique meeting ids? etc.) so the conflict resolution ends up fixing the existing meeting instead of adding a second one? And so on. Once you do that, where you store the data on both partitions (probably completely different database implementations in the client and server) and which protocol you send the updates on become implementation details.

There's another issue you'll need to consider. When do we do these reconciliations? In many systems like I listed above, the reconciliation happens on read: If the client wants to read data and we suddenly see two conflicting versions on two reachable nodes, we reconcile. In your calendar application, you need a slightly different approach: It is possible that the client will only ever try to read (use) the calendar when not connected. You need to use the rare opportunities when he is connected to reconcile all the differences. Moreover, you may need to "push" changes - e.g., if the data on the server changed, the client may need to be told, "hey, I have some changed data, come and reconcile", so the end-user will immediately see an announcement on a new meeting, for example, that was added remotely (e.g., perhaps by a different user sharing the same calendar). You'll need to figure out how you want to do this. Again, there is no magic solution like "use Cassandra".

Comment: thank you for the answer. It helps me alot, my prof. said exactly the same thing to me today. Now i know how to go on.